# R substitute of `:::` operator to pass CRAN check

Tags: r, devtools, cran

I'm developing a package which breaks some CRAN standard, therefore I don't plan to submit it to CRAN but I would like to make my travis CHECK as strict as possible.

Is there a way to substitute `:::` operator so it can pass `--as-cran` check?
Or is there a way I can suppress this one particular warning while making check?

The second question might be even more valuable as I may run into other `--as-cran` exception.

I'm aware I can ask package maintainer to export particular function but looking for some less intrusive solution.

Comment: copy the function you need to your package but dont export it?

Comment: It uses tons of dependent not exported functions from the package which I want to access. That means more or less fork of that package to make it work and add my functionality.

Comment: @Jan Yes, that’s what it means.

Comment: See `?getFromNamespace` or look at the source code for `:::` and use that.

Comment: The main problem is that even if you have a workaround the non-exported functions can unexpectedly change invalidating your package.  Best would be to ask maintainer if they would export them which would make them more official or maybe the maintainer has alternative suggestions.  In fact, the maintainer may have not exported them for good reason such as an intention to change them in the future.

Comment: @G. Grothendieck the function is exported as S3 method. And regarding invalidating my package... better than relying on changes in exported or non-exported function (doesn't really matter as exported funs still can break your package) is to make good test scenario and set travis, That what my aim is. `:::` is in fact not so scary as the other dirty stuff I'm doing [here](https://github.com/jangorecki/dtq/blob/f0246ffb4fb284ea36f40bb03bdb771e2bd86820/R/zzz.R#L3).

Comment: The exported functions are part of the documented part of  a package and changes are normally documented in a NEWS file which makes them less likely to be changed and when they are at least the changes are more visible.  Not so with unexported functions.

Comment: Why do you need direct access to the function if it is exported as an as S3 method?

Comment: @BrodieG see my code linked in previous comment, or vignette in that package. It injects an expression to that function. Simply speaking I use what R language allows me to, and the output is relatively valuable.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but you should look into `trace` as it might be a better way of achieving what you are doing there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So long as you promise you aren't going to get me on the PBR blacklist:

```
`%:::%` <- `:::`
```

Then use `%:::%` as you would `:::`.  This will pass the check, but really not recommended, and as people are suggesting in the comments, all you are doing is faking it to get a (fake) travis gold star since accessing non-exported functions is definitely a no no in terms of CRAN acceptable things to do (and with good reason).

There are some notes that show up during `--as-cran` checks that you can circumvent without going against the spirit of the note, but this isn't really one of those cases.

Comment: … or just  don’t run `R CMD CHECK`. Both solutions are equivalent. ;-)

Comment: ... or just use one of those new r modules ;-}

Comment: @rawr, what are you referring to?

Comment: cool, I will create `%:::%` just in the frame where I need to use it so should be safe. In fact I can remove it just after use.
@rawr what do you mean?

Comment: @BrodieG (and  Jan) That's most likely a reference to [this](https://github.com/klmr/modules).